# JavaScript Date Format: Format The Day e.x (Mon)

Tags: javascript, html, css, date, format

I am trying to make a basic week calendar. The numbers are working fine but I don't know how to exactly do that, to get the days in String. For example I need this format:
Today is: Mon
Tomorrow will be: Tue

I tried some code but all I could do is to write the day like that:
Today is: Monday.

So is there any option to make the "Monday" to "Mon"?

Also I need to to that, to get the value of tomorrow and yesterday.
I mean:
Yesterday: Sun
Today: Mon
Tomorrow: Tue

But when I tried to make it there was an error. Any idea how to make it workable?

By the way heres my tries:

```js
var options = {
  weekday: 'long'
};
var today = new Date();
var option = {
  weekday: 'long'
};
var tomorrow = new Date();
var todaya1 = tomorrow.getDate() + 1;
document.getElementById("today").innerHTML = today.toLocaleDateString("en-US", options);
document.getElementById("tomorrow").innerHTML = todaya1.toLocaleDateString("en-US", option);
```

```css
#today {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<span id="today"></span>
<span id="tomorrow"></span>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have console errors because `tomorrow.getDate() + 1;` is not a date object

You need to create two date objects

Also you only need one set of options if they are the same

```js
const options = { weekday: 'short' };

var today = new Date();
var tomorrow = new Date()
tomorrow.setDate(tomorrow.getDate() + 1);

document.getElementById("today").innerHTML = today.toLocaleDateString("en-US", options);
document.getElementById("tomorrow").innerHTML = tomorrow.toLocaleDateString("en-US", options);
```

```css
#today {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<span id="today"></span>
<span id="tomorrow"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const days = ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'];
const todayDate = new Date();
const todayDay = days[todayDate.getDay()];
const tomorrowDate = new Date(todayDate);
tomorrowDate.setDate(tomorrowDate.getDate() + 1);
const tomorrowDay = days[tomorrowDate.getDay()];

const todayEl = document.getElementById('today');
const tomorrowEl = document.getElementById('tomorrow');

todayEl.textContent = todayDay;
tomorrowEl.textContent = tomorrowDay;
```

```html
<span id="today"></span>
<span id="tomorrow"></span>
```

Comment: Actullay using `{ weekday: 'shrort' }` with `toLocaleDateString` is a better way.